# NetBeans new language support with Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I'm building a NetBeans plugin for a new language, using [the Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/). I've followed (roughly) [this tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-javacc-lexer.html), but I end up not being able to compile (stack trace below).

Using the same code and module dependencies with a standard (Ant-based) NetBeans module project, it compiles properly. The class it can't find seems to be available in another module (org-netbeans-modules-editor-codetemplates), but I don't need that module when I use the Ant-based project. Also, if I do add that module, I get a similar error for a different class that I can't find in another module, which makes me thing I'm doing something wrong. Am I missing something?

**The stack trace:**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/editor/codetemplates/CodeTemplateCompletionProvider
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.core.LanguageRegistrationProcessor.registerCodeCompletion(LanguageRegistrationProcessor.java:270)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.core.LanguageRegistrationProcessor.handleProcess(LanguageRegistrationProcessor.java:160)
    at org.openide.filesystems.annotations.LayerGeneratingProcessor.process(LayerGeneratingProcessor.java:121)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess0(JavacCompiler.java:551)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.editor.codetemplates.CodeTemplateCompletionProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
```

**My dependencies**

```
    <!-- Common Scripting Language API (new) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-csl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Datasystems API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-loaders</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dialogs API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-dialogs</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- File System API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-filesystems</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lexer API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-lexer</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lookup API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Nodes API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-nodes</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Text API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-text</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- UI Utilities API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-awt</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Utilities API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Window System API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-windows</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably have found and error in the generation of maven's pom.xml file for the platform's artifacts. While org-netbeans-modules-csl-api jar contains a module dependency on codetemplates module (org.netbeans.modules.editor.codetemplates/1 = 1), it's not present in the list of resolved dependencies. Please file an issue against https://netbeans.org/bugzilla component:apisupport subcomponent: maven.

Thanks.

PS: The workaround is indeed the path you have tried but didn't finish. Keep on adding missing dependencies until the annotation processor's runtime dependencies are satisfied.

The dependencies required (for NetBeans 7.3.1) are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-editor-codetemplates</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-editor-errorstripe</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding the above dependencies fixed it. Bug is: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232648